# I can't delete this folder which contain virus, it keeps being recreated when deleted

Tags: windows-10, virus-removal, malware-removal

So today I was desperate to find a space for my c drive since I want to install something new. in that case I'm scanning my c drive for extra space. and I found this weird folder with weird content. I don't think far so I just delete it. suddenly, I can't use firefox because of certificate issue. I already sorted this out, fortunately. apparently, there is this process going on ZGU5ODFhYThhMjNkMT.exe that make firefox detect it as a man in the middle. I recognize that name which is from the weird folder I deleted. when I open c program files again, I found the weird folder is still there.

so this folder is recreated and begin the process when deleted? I don't know

anyone know how to actually delete this folder? or trace back what caused it to be recreated?

edit:
i found that my windows defender keeps adding exceptions for these folder/programs. so windows defender scan won't be any use

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First, go to Task Manager, and see if cmd.EXE is running. If it is, end it. It can recreate files when you delete them. After that, go to your 'Startup' folder and see if there is a bat, vbs, and/or cmd file (or any unknown files), then delete them (after ending CMD). After this, delete the folder (NmE3YmY3ZDI), and restart. If it's still there, don't hesitate to leave a comment. Hope your PC gets better!